# Bulk upsert stored procedure

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

If anyone can help, I'm new to cosmos and JS. I have a requirement where data to be upserted in bulk and I found JavaScript for that, but that is failing.

Trying to call a stored procedure from python as:

```
client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_linkOut, [new_docs,True], options = options)
```

or

```
client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_linkOut, [new_docs], options = options)
```

but I'm getting an error show below. But I think it should not arise as error 409 this code is written. Can you please help.

> HTTPFailure: Status code: 400 Sub-status: 409
>   {"code":"BadRequest",
>   "message":"Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource with specified id or name already exists.\"]}\r\nStack trace: Error: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource with specified id or name already exists.\"]}.

JavaScript stored procedure:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//------------------------------------------------------------

function bulkImport(docs, upsert) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

    // The count of imported docs, also used as current doc index.
    var count = 0;
    var errorCodes = { CONFLICT: 409 };

    // Validate input.
    if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

    var docsLength = docs.length;

    if (docsLength == 0) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
        return;
    }

    // Call the create API to create a document.
    tryCreate(docs[count], callback);

    // Note that there are 2 exit conditions:
    // 1) The createDocument request was not accepted.
    // In this case the callback will not be called, we just call
    // setBody and we are done.
    // 2) The callback was called docs.length times.
    // In this case all documents were created and we don’t need to call
    // tryCreate anymore. Just call setBody and we are done.
    function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
        var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, { disableAutomaticIdGeneration : true}, callback);

    // If the request was accepted, callback will be called.
    // Otherwise report current count back to the client,
    // which will call the script again with remaining set of docs.
    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
}

// To replace the document, first issue a query to find it and then call replace.
function tryReplace(doc, callback) {
    var parsedDoc = JSON.parse(doc);
    retrieveDoc(parsedDoc, null, function(retrievedDocs){
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(retrievedDocs[0]._self, parsedDoc, callback);
        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    });
}

function retrieveDoc(doc, continuation, callback) {
    var query = "select * from root r where r.id = '" + doc.id + "'";
    var requestOptions = { continuation : continuation }; 
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function(err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
            callback(retrievedDocs);
        } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            retrieveDoc(doc, responseOptions.continuation, callback);            
        } else {
            throw "Error in retrieving document: " + doc.id;
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
}

// This is called when collection.createDocument is done in order to
// process the result.
function callback(err, doc, options) {
    if (err) {
        // Replace the document if status code is 409 and upsert is enabled
        if(upsert && err.number == errorCodes.CONFLICT) {
            return tryReplace(docs[count], callback);
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }

       // One more document has been inserted, increment the count.
      count++;
      if (count >= docsLength) {
        // If we created all documents, we are done. Just set the response.
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
      } else {
        // Create next document.
        tryCreate(docs[count], callback);
      } 
}
```

As stored procedure gets two parameters, I tried with earlier mentioned both ways, but failed.

---

Update Code:

```
print (param)
[[{'ACCOUNT': '1', 'id': '1', 'CASE_N': 'AB'}], True]

client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_link, [param],options=options)
```

Still get 400 error:

> 400 Sub-status: 400 {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message:
>   {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing function.
>   Exception = Error: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"One of the specified inputs is
>   invalid\\"]}\r\nStack trace: Error: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"One of the
>   specified inputs is invalid\\"]}\n

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the stored proc,
1. removed upsert input parameter and make it hard coded,
2. removed line var parsedDoc = JSON.parse(doc); with var parsedDoc = doc;

Now procedure working fine.

Comment: Changing var parsedDoc = JSON.parse(doc); with var parsedDoc = doc; worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you follow this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop/blob/master/src/BulkImportScript.js) and this code works fine.Based on your error log, i believe your execution never jumps into the upsert branch. Possibly you passed the parameters into SP incorrectly.

No modification for bulkimport SP, for your code instead.

```
from pydocumentdb import document_client

endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
primaryKey = "***";

client = document_client.DocumentClient(endpoint, {'masterKey': primaryKey})

options = {"partitionKey": "A"}

def create_cosmos_entity(jobid):
    return {
        'JobID': jobid,
        'id': jobid,
        "name": "A"
    }
bulkdos = []
bulkdos.append(create_cosmos_entity('1'))

param = []
param.append(bulkdos)
param.append(True)

sproc_link = "dbs/db/colls/coll/sprocs/bulkimport"
q = client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_link, [param], options)
```

You could refer to this thread:[DocumentDB: bulkImport Stored Proc - Getting 400 Error on Array/JSON issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748684/documentdb-bulkimport-stored-proc-getting-400-error-on-array-json-issue/49450200#49450200)

> The "docs" must be an array of array of params, otherwise, the
>   procedure executor will treat them as multiple params of the
>   procedure, not a single-array-param.

Comment: print (param), [[{'ACCOUNT': '1', 'id': '1', 'CASE_N': 'AB'}], True]

Comment: client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_link, [param],options=options)

Comment: Status code: 400 Sub-status: 400
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"One of the specified inputs is invalid\\\"]}\\r\\nStack trace: Error: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"One of the specified inputs is invalid\\\"]}\\n

Comment: @RIRAY Update your code in your question,will test again for you.

Comment: @RIRAY need your python relate code because i test my code successfully. It seems that you did something wrong with param input based on the new 400 error.

Comment: I'm using the same code you have shared above and tried in python 3.and getting

Comment: HTTPFailure: Status code: 400 Sub-status: 400
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"One of the specified inputs is invalid\\\"]}\\r\\nStack trace: Error: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"One of the specified inputs is invalid\\\"]}\\n   at callback (script.js:76:17)\\n   at Anonymous function (bulkImport.js:685:29)\"]}\r\nActivityId: bdaa06be-abb3-492b-83ee-beef8900301a, Request URI: /apps/796f6a08-ae9e-4a5f-8014-6b8972ffefdc/services/de4e4306-7fa7-4c40-b795-2241063e17da/partitions/80d17e6b-bc3d-46

Comment: if you drop me mail at ray.riju@gmail.com I'll share the code as I can't share it here due to not having sufficient character in comments box.

Comment: @RIRAY You could edit your question,not in comment.